# How to add overlay to image picker in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image-processing, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to add an overlay to image taken with imagePicker such as a frame, shown during snap taking. I was trying to use the following code:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Insert the overlay
self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;

[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

But this helps when changing the image picker skin. How can I add and process an overlay with the snapshot?

Comment: Are you able to find anything regarding, Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you need to merge a picture taken with another UIImageView that contains an image, here's a useful snippet:

**yourFile.h:**

```
UIImage *combinedImage;
```

**yourFile.m:**

```
-(void)savePicture { // call this method from an IBAction button

        // Crop a Combined Image from the taken picture
        CGRect rect = [_imagePreview bounds];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);


     // Render both images, the captured one from the camera and the UIImageView that is over that picture
    [__myCapturedImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [_overlayImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        _myCapturedImage.image = combinedImage;


  // Automatically Save the Image into Photo Album (if you want to do so)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combinedImage, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

Hope this helps!

PS: we have made a nice template that actually processes overlays images (which are frames around images) here: http://codecanyon.net/item/picshape-frame-image-editor-full-app-template/7852895?ref=fvimagination

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reference!
Regarding this - if the overlayImageView has an offset, when combining the two images from the views, the position of the overlay is set back to top. How can I use the original offset when comgining?